# redirect to url based on php variable

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting a `Internal 500 Error` at present with my code below

What I have is a games site that calls it’s games (around 100) with one single php file:

```
game-play.php?content=GAME1
game-play.php?content=GAME2
game-play.php?content=GAME3
```

What I am trying to do is permanently redirect each game to its equivalent static `.html` page with the same name as the argument supplied in the above links in a new folder.

So the above would redirect to:

```
/games/GAME1.html
/games/GAME2.html
/games/GAME3.html
```

The code I currently have below is giving me internal 500 eror:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} content=([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?  /games/?content.html [L,NC]
```

It seems like such a simple thing but I have tried countless variations with either internal error or page 404 or nothing at all.

Comment: There is no `content.html` in your URLs but your rule is using it.

Comment: I thought that ?content was holding the information for the page hence ?content.html would redirect to the page in the content variable if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+game-play\.php\?content=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /games/%1.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^games/([^./]+)\.html$ /game-play.php?content=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: anubhava, This looks promising. thank you. only problem I have is the game still loads as normal even though I have not created the new games in the games folder it points too. so the browser url reads www.domainname.com/games/gamesname which is what I was looking for but even though that page does not exist yet the game still loads. hope that makes sense. would adding .html after the %1 on line 2 give me www.domainname.com/games/gamesname.html ? if so that might be exactly right because that currently gives me a 404 error which is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect
http://www.domain.com/game-play.php?content=GAME1
to
http://www.domain.com/game/GAME1.html

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /game-play.php?content=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hey David, Thanks but no joy there. It has no effect at all the link goes exactly where it would normally go.